# How do you find out what the "system default encoding" is?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-2.x

[The documentation for fileobject.encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.encoding) mentions that it can be `None`, and in that case, the "system default encoding" is used.

How can I find out what this encoding is?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You should use [`sys.getdefaultencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getdefaultencoding)

Comment: For a quick check via terminal: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())"`.

Comment: What is the difference between `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and `locale.getencoding()`?